# How to read this table in a datasheet

Tags: memory, identification, device, documentation

I'm trying to get the device ID out of dataflash memory using an mbed. I'm trying to understand this table that is in the documentation for the memory. I understand that ABh, 90h, and 9Fh are the instructions that have to be sent to the memory to get the ID. What is listed under them? Are those the codes that will be returned? What is (ID7-ID0), (ID15-ID0), and (M7-M0)? What is EFh?

[image]

The full datasheet has been delisted from the manufacturer website, but it's still available [here](http://datasheet.octopart.com/W25P80VSSIG-Winbond-datasheet-22205.pdf) on octopart.

Answer (score 1):

in table 10.2.2 states M7-M0 are part of the JEDEC register, same with ID15-ID0. 
so when you send your command to read that register it will return those portions of the Register, (MSB first).
Ehf is the JEDEC manufacture ID, I believe that is the same for all winbond chips in that family.

Comment: So if I wanted to get the device ID would this work?      pc.printf("ID = %d\r\n", spi.write(0x9f));
     pc.printf("memory type = %d\r\n", spi.write(0x00));
     pc.printf("capacity = %d\r\n", spi.write(0x00));

Comment: I don't know specifically if that would work, since i am not familiar with that language but sending 9F should return the info on that register.